# “Undefined Reference” error when trying to complie using Makefile

Tags: c, header, header-files

This is my first time making my own header file but I keep getting undefined Reference error for 'ft_isdigit'. I dont see what I am doing wrong. Can some one please help me figure out what I am missing?

main.c file

```
#include "libft.h"
int main ()
{
        if (ft_isdigit(5))
        {
                printf("Digit");

        }
        else
                printf("NOPE");

}
```

ft_isdigit.c file

```
#include "libft.h"

int ft_isdigit(int c)
{
  if (c>='0' && c<= '9')
  {
    return(1);
  }
  else
    return(0);
}
```

libft.h file

```
#ifndef LIBFT_H
# define LIBFT_H
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_isdigit(int c);

#endif
```

and the Makefile

```
Library     = libft

files      = ft_isdigit \
             
Compiler    = gcc

CmpFlags    = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

OUTN    = $(Library).a

CFILES  = $(files:%=%.c)

OFILES  = $(files:%=%.o)

NAME    = $(OUTN)

$(NAME):
    $(Compiler) $(CmpFlags) -c $(CFILES) -I./
    ar -rc $(OUTN) $(OFILES)

all: $(NAME)

clean:
    rm -f $(NAME)
    rm -f $(OFILES)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all, clean, fclean, re
```

Comment: Headers are only one part of the story: They tell the compiler what the symbols look like, e.g. what a function's signature is. To get the actual code, you must link against the object file or library that contains the implementation. How to do that depends on which compiler you use. For gcc, it might be enough to specify more than one source file and say `gcc main.c libft.c`.

Comment: I tried what you said and This is the exact error that I get /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSUHbO1.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `ft_isdigit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If the second code snippet you posted is in `libft.c`, that shouldn't happen. Perhaps you should edit your question to include the Makefile. By the way, your `ft_isdigit(c)` function will always return true. You probably want `&&` there instead of `||`.

Comment: Are you sure you got the case and spelling right in `ccSUHbO1`?

Comment: @MOehm I have added the Makefile as well.

Comment: @Lundin I dont even know how that file is getting created as i have not named any file in that way knowingly.

Comment: As fas as I can see, your makefile creates `libft.a` from `ft_isdigit.o`, which is compiled from `gcc -c ft_isdigit.c`. If you want to use that lib with your `main.c`, do something like `gcc main.c -L. -lft`.